# YAML::Syck generates list instead of hash

Tags: perl, yaml

If I run the below script, then the two hashes are the same, but when I look at how the yaml file looks I see this very weird format

```
--- nicPri
--- ixgbe1
--- nicPub
--- ixgbe2
--- slaves
--- 
47: 10.10.47.47
48: 10.10.10.48
--- ipPri
--- 10.10.10.46
```

which doesn't look like a normal yaml file. I would have expected something like this

```
---
users:
  abc: abc
  ssd: www
01102:
  members:
    - abc
    - ssd
---
```

**Question**

Can anyone see why I this this weird yaml format?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use YAML::Syck;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

our %c = (
    slaves => {
        "47" => "10.10.47.47",
        "48" => "10.10.10.48",
    },
    ipPri         => "10.10.10.46",
    nicPub        => "ixgbe2",
    nicPri        => "ixgbe1",
);

our $config = "/tmp/config.yaml";

# create new yaml file
system("rm -f $config");
open F, '>', $config;
print F YAML::Syck::Dump(%c);
close F;
my %cfg = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($config);

print Dumper \%cfg;
print Dumper \%c;
```

Comment: Can you post the **real** output you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

`YAML::Syck` (as `YAML`) [expects](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod#Dump-list-of-Perl-data-structures) `hashref`, not `hash`:

```
print F YAML::Syck::Dump(\%c);
```

Also `LoadFile` returns `hashref`, not `hash`:

```
my $cfg = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($config);    
print Dumper $cfg;
```

### Other improvements

First of all, you don't really need `our` here. Your `%c` means pretty much the same as `%main::c`. `our` creates the alias for the *package* variable. And this is not what you want. You should just use regular scoped variables via `my`, e. g. `my %c`.

Using `open` with filehandle is not considered a good practice anymore, use scalar instead:

```
open(my $fh, '>', $config);
```

Also you can use `$fh->print` instead of `print $fh`. If you still prefer to use `print $fh`, you should use `print {$fh}` instead (according to [Conway](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/InputOutput/RequireBracedFileHandleWithPrint.pm)).

Comment: Yes please improve the code if possible. With the hashref I get the correct yaml format, but now `print Dumper \%cfg;` gives `'HASH(0x821474c)' => undef` which was correct before.

Comment: I added some extra details.